# how to fix the error Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean' in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using the following code and getting the error as below:

Error:
 error TS2345: Argument of type '(item: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number, obj: any[]) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Code:

```
addToCart(product) {
    if (!this.productArr.length) {
      this.productArr.push(product);
    } else {
      let flag = false;
      this.productArr.find((item: any) => {
        if (item.name === product.name) {
          item.count = product.count;
          flag = true;
        }
      });
      if (!flag) {
        this.productArr.push(product);
      }
    }
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.productArr);
  }
```

Any idea how can we fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
addToCart(product) {
    if (!this.productArr.length) {
      this.productArr.push(product);
    } else {
      let flag = false;
      this.productArr.forEach((item: any) => { // change this line
        if (item.name === product.name) {
          item.count = product.count;
          flag = true;
        }
      });
      if (!flag) {
        this.productArr.push(product);
      }
    }
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.productArr);
  }
```

Change the `.find` to a `.forEach`. The `.find` expects a return of a boolean value of when it found the element you're looking for. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: While correct, `foreach` will continue running after an element has been found. `find` has the (unintended by OP?) side-effect of stopping after a `true` is returned. Alhough `some` or `every` may be more appropriate (and clearer!) here, depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning a value in the arrow function you pass as parameter to `find`. You need to return a boolean here.

```js
this.productArr.find((item: any) => {
    if (item.name === product.name) {
        item.count = product.count;
        flag = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Note that this will also stop further iterations over the array, which may or may not be your intention. Use `forEach` if you need to find all occurences of `item` where the name is the same as that of the product.

The better solution would be to use `some` or `every` instead of find, depending on whether or not you want to apply this operation to multiple products, since using `find` implies that you're looking to find something and not performing alterations to an item.

```js
// Will stop after the first time `true` is returned
this.productArr.some((item: any) => {
    if (item.name === product.name) {
        item.count = product.count;
        flag = true;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
addToCart(product: any): void {
    // find will return your product, and it only need a boolean as condition for the arrow function
    const product = this.productArr.find((item: any) => item.name === product.name);

    // If you don't have some products or you don't find your product, you push it
    if (!this.productArr.length || !product) {
      this.productArr.push(product);
    }

    // if you find your product, you update your item.coun
    if (product) {
        item.count = product.count;
    }

    this.cartService.addToCart(this.productArr);
}
```

Have a look on this [article](https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c), it explains actually how to the find/map/foreach operators.

Comment: I don't think your last statement about being able to remove the parameter is true, provided the Service is an instance of a class. In that case, the `this` inside the `cartService.addToCart`-function will resolve to the `cartService`-instance and not the owner of the `addToCart`-function from which it is called.

Comment: Correct, I though it was the same service. I'll update